# Why xv6 scheduler calls sti() in the begining of every loop?

Tags: operating-system, kernel, xv6

The companion book says

> The reason to enable interrupts periodically on an idling CPU is that
>   there might be no RUNNABLE process because processes (e.g., the shell)
>   are waiting for I/O; if the scheduler left interrupts disabled all the
>   time, the I/O would never arrive.

But I think we just need to call sti() once before the outter for-loop, since everytime we release ptable.lock, the interrupts are enabled again.

Comment: Maybe you should try removing the repeated `sti` and see if the scheduler hangs or continues normally.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that `schedule()` is called with interrupts disabled, in which case releasing the ptable spinlock will not reenable them.

Comment: Yes, that's right. But I think we only need to enable interrupts at the begining of scheduler(). Why do we need to do this repeatedly? Can you give me a scenario when it is needed? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the code for [releasing a lock](https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-public/blob/34f060c3dcf3bf3dde683df9ff9872bc9f1d5d14/spinlock.c#L47), you will see that it does not explicitly enable interrupts. Instead it uses the function `popcli`.

```c
void release ( struct spinlock* lk )
{
    ...
    popcli();  // enable interrupts
}
```

The function `popcli` **does not always** enable interrupts. It is used in tandem with `pushcli` to track nesting level. "Pushcli/popcli are like cli/sti except that they are matched: it takes two popcli to undo two pushcli". [<sup>1</sup>](https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-public/blob/34f060c3dcf3bf3dde683df9ff9872bc9f1d5d14/spinlock.c#L100)

```c
void popcli ( void )
{
    // If interrupts are enabled, panic...
    if ( readeflags() & FL_IF )
    {
        panic( "popcli: interruptible" );
    }

    // Track depth of cli nesting
    mycpu()->ncli -= 1;

    // Popped more than were pushed...
    if ( mycpu()->ncli < 0 )
    {
        panic( "popcli" );
    }

    // Reached outermost, so restore interrupt state
    if ( mycpu()->ncli == 0 && mycpu()->intena )
    {
        sti();  // enable interrupts
    }
}
```

Whereas `popcli` **sometimes** enables interrupts, `pushcli` **always** disables interrupts.

```c
void pushcli ( void )
{
    int eflags;

    eflags = readeflags();

    // Disable interrupts
    cli();

    // Save interrupt state at start of outermost
    if ( mycpu()->ncli == 0 )
    {
        mycpu()->intena = eflags & FL_IF;
    }

    // Track depth of cli nesting
    mycpu()->ncli += 1;
}
```

By explicitly calling `sti`, the scheduler overrides whatever the current push/popcli state is. I think this provides the brief window desired to allow an IO interrupt to occur. I.e. the period of time between the call to `sti` and the call to `cli` (via `acquire` -> `pushcli` -> `cli`).

```c
void scheduler ( void )
{
    ...
    for ( ;; )
    {
        // Enable interrupts on this processor.
        sti();

        // Acquire process table lock
        acquire( &ptable.lock );

        // Loop over process table looking for process to run.
        for ( p = ptable.proc; p < &ptable.proc[ NPROC ]; p += 1 )
        {
            ...
        }

        // Release process table lock
        release( &ptable.lock );
    }
}
```